# Как найти элемент по классу с помощью querySelector()?

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

У меня есть кнопка на странице с классом copy_button, как мне найти ее по классу с помощью querySelector?

```css
body{
    background-color: wheat;
}

.copy_button{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #b3a58b;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0px;
}

.copy_button:hover{
    background-color: #827865;
}

.copy_button:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>JS Test</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="csscode.css">
 </head>

 <body>
   <button class="copy_button">Copy!</button>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

эм.... `document.querySelector('.copy_button')`

---

```js
alert(document.querySelector('.copy_button').textContent);
```

```html
<button class="copy_button">Copy!</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я просто не понимал как найти кнопку именно по классу.
Еще такой вопрос, для чего используется alert и .textContent в коде который вы приложили?

Comment: @dhelfy что значит `найти кнопку именно по классу`? вы имеете в виду через `getElementsByClassName`?..................." для чего используется alert и .textContent в коде который вы приложили" - чтобы показать, что код рабочий и кнопка находится и выводится её содержимое

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: _"Что за ужас тут творится???"_ )))

Comment: @UModeL сам в шоке ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯